# Using struts 1 CSRF protection on links

Tags: java, struts, csrf

I'm looking at stopping CSRF, and while Struts 1 has saveToken, isTokenValid, and resetToken which work nicely for forms they do not seem to work for links. By this I mean links such as `www.mysite.com/action/doSomething?id=123`

Is there a way to use this functionality to stop CSRF with these links? Unfortunately upgrading Struts is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hidden field in the jsp page to store current session values and then validate in the action class.

please check the following link for more details
[Cross-site request forgery prevention using struts token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303635/cross-site-request-forgery-prevention-using-struts-token)